# track the user who downloaded my wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

Is there a tool or way to know who are the users who downloaded my WordPress plugins and get their Location, Operating System they used, Bowser they used and their age so that I can output it to the download per day under the advanced menu. As a default, It can only track the number of downloads per day but I can't get more details.

This is a sample picture from Wordpress.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has many Download-Plugins which track stats like that. Just search "Download" under plugins and choose the one you like. But you can't track the age of the user unsless you ask them.